# Handle Permissions Request Result Without Subclassing Activity and Overriding onRequestPermissionsResult Method

Tags: java, cordova, permissions

I am calling a permissions request from a non-`Activity` based class inside of a Cordova plugin, and the main activity of my application cannot be extended so I cannot implement/override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method of the activity. I need to run an event after the user has authorized permissions like the commented pseudocode lambda below, but I am not sure how. I have tried creating my own `Activity` subclass and implementing this method, but I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private void saveAndOpenFile() {
        int permission = 
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                cordova.getActivity(), 
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                cordova.getActivity(),
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ); /*.then((int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantedResults) -> {
                // Do something crazy
            });*/
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest following the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#android-permissions) on this one.

In short, it appears you should use `cordova.hasPermission` to check if we have the permission, then use `cordova.requestPermission`, which "will call the activity and cause a prompt to appear, asking for the permission. Once the user has the permission, the result must be handled with the `onRequestPermissionResult` method, which every plugin should override." So, it sounds like `CordovaPlugin` offers an empty base implementation of `onRequestPermissionResult` that your plugin should override.

Granted, I imagine you can probably get away with calling `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` and `Acitivity.requestPermissions`, but either way, your plugin should override `onRequestPermissionResult`.

```java
class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private void saveAndOpenFile() {
        /* check permissions
                  ...       
                           */
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                          int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {
        /* check permission granted and proceed accordingly */
    }

}
```